# PHP preg_match_all not matching properly

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to get some data off of a website source code. What I am trying to do is get everything after `/collections/(whatever that follows here)`. My pattern matched "most" of what I am looking for. The problem occurs when my `preg_match_all` gets to a pattern with the "&", at which point it will simply read to the point of "&" and stop reading the remainder. Here is my script:

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.harrisfarm.com.au/');
$pattern = '/collections([\w-&\/]*)/i';
preg_match_all($pattern, $processedHomePage, $collections);
print_r($collections);
```

Notice that when printing like this, things after the "&" are ignored, meaning it will get me this:

```
/collections/seafood/Shellfish-&
```

But when I am pattern matching on one string such as below:

```
 $subject = 'a href="/collections/organic/Pantry/sickmonster/grandma"  <a href="/collections/seafood/Shellfish-&-Crustaceans">Oysters, Shellfish & Crustaceans';
```

it gets me everything I want:

```
/collections/seafood/Shellfish-&-Crustaceans
```

So I wonder... why is this happening? I am really stumped here.

Comment: Seems like [it should match](http://regex101.com/r/tY7sE1/1)?  Are you sure the `&` isn't being escaped to `&amp;` somewhere along the way, since you're dealing with webpages?

Comment: i think the "&" are being escaped into &amp; somehow. but i wonder how can i keep it from doing that? is there any magical function from php that will stop it from doing it?

Comment: What are doing between $homepage and $processedHomePage? I guess there is code missing.

Comment: Depends where it's happening.  I suspect the original webpage is sending them out, possibly also encoded as `%26` rather than just an `&` as it would seem odd to include an ampersand in the URL of a link in the way you've posted

Comment: No, there is no problem with the above code when you use $homepage instead of $processedHomePage in preg_match_all.

Comment: thanks guys! you are all great helps. super thanks from me to you. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with the provided code when you use $homepage instead of $processedHomePage in preg_match_all.

---

BTW:
You should escape the minus sign in squared brackets (or write it at the beginning or end of the expression in squared brackets), but surprisingly it makes no difference in your case:

> $pattern = '/collections([-\w&/]*)/i';

See http://php.net/manual/regexp.reference.meta.php for further information.

Comment: Whilst I agree you're better off not putting a hyphen in the middle of a group, I don't think that's the problem here.  [This shows](http://regex101.com/r/tY7sE1/1) it working fine, and in the OP it's unlikely that it would have matched the `-` before the `&` if it needed to be escaped

Comment: nope, not the problem with hyphen. tried and still the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem is - maybe this will help others later.

I had tried to use `htmlspecialchars()` to convert the url http://www.harrisfarm.com.au/ and then read it in as a string.  This converted some special characters like `&` and some other things, into something with many characters.

The conversion of `&` turns it into `&amp;` which has a `;`, and that's not in my regular expression.  Since `;` is not  part of regular expression, the regex stopped matching at that point.

Comment: Glad you found out the problem - in any future questions please include all pertinent code, as this would have highlighted the issue right away :)

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**

```
$re = "/\\/collections([\\w\\-\\&\\/;]*)/mi";
$str = "<a href=\"/collections/seafood/Shellfish-&amp;-Crustaceans\">Oysters, Shellfish & Crustaceans';\n<a href=\"/collections/seafood/Shellfish-&-Crustaceans\">Oysters,collections Shellfish & Crustaceans';";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

[live demo](http://regex101.com/r/oQ4qB6/2)

**your update code**

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.harrisfarm.com.au/');
$pattern = "/\\/collections([\\w\\-\\&\\/;]*)/mi";
preg_match_all($pattern, $homepage, $collections);
print_r($collections);
```